# Issue in creating custom module

Tags: magento2, php, module, admin, controllers

I have created a custom news module in Magento 2.

News module includes admin listing and edit.

But it is showing fatal error.

> Fatal error: Class Namespace\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Enquiry
>   contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or
>   implement the remaining methods
>   (Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::execute)

My controller code is given below

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Controller\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Namespace\Module\Model\EnquiryFactory;

class Enquiry extends Action
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * Result page factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Enquiry model factory
     *
     * @var \Mbf\Enquries\Model\EnquiryFactory
     */
    protected $_enquiryFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param EnquiryFactory $enquiryFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        EnquiryFactory $enquiryFactory
    ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_enquiryFactory = $enquiryFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Enquiry access rights checking
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Namespace_Module::manage_enquiry');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing execute() method in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

you were missing the **execute()** meth0d

```
public function execute()
    { 
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $this->initPage($resultPage)->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Spacename News'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
    protected function initPage($resultPage)
    {
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Spacename_Moduelname::news')
            ->addBreadcrumb(__('Spacename News'), __('News'))
            ->addBreadcrumb(__('Manage news'), __('Manage news'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an `execute()` method in your controller.

It depends on what you want to achieve.

A simple example could be:

```
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();

    return $resultPage;
}
```